# How to close the request after its complete using Guzzle 6.x Client

Tags: php, zend-framework2, guzzle6

I have a task to identify the existence of the links. As a result I am using guzzle client to identify if the link is existence or not, i.e if the response header received is 200, then the link is existence else not.

Below is my code snippet

```
public function checkUrl($url) {
    $result['isValid'] = false;
    try {
        $response = $this->client->get($url, ['verify', false]);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $result['isValid'] = false;
        $result['message'] = 'Some error message';
        return $result;
    }
    if ($response->getStatusCode() == Response::STATUS_CODE_200) {
        $result['isValid'] = true;
    }
    $result['message'] = 'Success - ' . $response->getStatusCode();
    $response->getBody()->close();

    return $result;
}
```

where `$this->client` is initialized to `GuzzleHttp\Client` object once in the constructor

When I run my script, after some time it throws me the error as follows:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: include(/project/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Model/ConsoleModel.php): failed to open stream: Too many open files`

And when I check the list of open files using the command `lsof -p <process id> -n`, I noticed that there lots of open files are as a result of guzzle request (i.e curl responses) and it seems to be the cause of this exception.

Is there any suggestion for the solution through which I can close those responses?

Comment: I wonder if theres a bug in Guzzle not closing those Curl requests.

Comment: @Flosculus What should be the best way to confirm whether its Guzzle bug or not?

Comment: Fire up XDebug, and dive into Guzzle.  We can probably help though, if you know exactly what version you are using.

Comment: @Flosculus I am using 6.2.3 version

Comment: Guzzle does not close the open streams by as it does not know for how long you need them. You can either manually close the open streams by calling `$response->getBody()->close()` or you can let the Stream object's destructor do it (for which you obviously need to "destruct" that object).

Comment: @mark.sagikazar, I tried `$response->getBody()->close()` but I still see there are open curl responses and I still get the same error for `Too many files open`.

Comment: @KD-Freelancer did you solve the issue?

Comment: @tylik No could not reach to any proper solution, hence have changed the implementation itself.

Comment: @KD-Freelancer could you please describe in couple of words? I can't find any proper solution. Have you dropped using Guzzlehttp, or somehow made it work without this bug?

Comment: Related issue. #1927 https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1927